# Can assert in pytest have third state - not Fail, not Success, but something as warning or 'weak' fail?

Tags: pytest, assert

I have items in stock from different companies.
And I do not know how to deal if numberOfItems == 0

If I do
assert numberOfItems > 0
Then if there is no item in stock it fails.

However I do not want it to fail instead show warning - this can be problem or not, but should not be showstopper for deployment lets say.

Not black/white but grey result of assert.

Comment: [There's an `xfail` status for tests that are expected to fail.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html)

Comment: I know xfail but I do not want to fail this case in any way. I really need something to be in report as "possible issue". Maybe if I see it three, four weeks then I can talk with product team or whoever.

Comment: If you want to implement a custom status, this would mean extending all relevant hooks that generate and proceed the test report, and there are some of them. Maybe simply issuing a `warnings.warn(...)` would be enough?

Comment: Hello @hoefling yes, I was checking that too, ok, I will read more and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is what you are looking for, but it helped me in a similar situation:

```
if numberOfItems == 0:
     pytest.skip("No items found")
```

There will be an output which is not PASSED, but it does not fail the run.

Comment: Nice idea! Although may not what the questioner, in my case it's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to pass it to the log as a warning. Unless you change your logging, these will show up in the output.

Assuming you have logging setup in your conftest:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_your_code():
    # other test code
    if numberOfItems == 0:
        log.warning("No items in stock for this company")
```

Otherwise, if you need it to be louder, use skip.

```
import pytest

def test_your_code():
    # other test code
    if numberOfItems == 0:
        pytest.skip("No items in stock for this company")
```